# Error uninstalling Google chromium

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-search, parrot-os

I downloaded Google chromium in /tmp directory in Linux. I want to uninstall it and by mistake I deleted /tmp directory.  Chromium is not uninstalling now. What can I do now?

Comment: When you say "not uninstalling", do you mean the application is still available from terminal? Or still available in desktop menus?

Comment: Do you mean google chrome or chromium? 'google chromium' isn't an official browser name

Comment: Google chrome and chromium browser both are available in desktop menu.

Comment: Can you say what steps you took to install it in the first place?

Comment: Is the application still in your path? What is the output of `which google-chrome-stable`?

Comment: i used this method:    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

Applications that show up in desktop menus are present because of associated `.desktop` files.

These are usually stored in `~/.local/share/applications`, `/usr/share/applications/` or `/usr/local/share/applications/`. Go to those directories and remove any files called chrome or chromium or anything similar, then reboot.

Comment: What about the /tmp directory? Do I need to create a new one ?

Comment: The /tmp directory should be re-created on next reboot anyway, and creating it yourself is likely to lead to permission errors

Comment: I can still see google chrome and chromiumm browser in search menu. However in applications list it is not available. What can i do now?

Comment: Try looking in `/usr/local/share/applications/` as well, I forgot to mention that

Comment: ┌─[root@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ #/usr/local/share/applications/
-bash: /usr/local/share/applications/: No such file or directory

Comment: what to do now?